# TableView reloaddata

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I wanted to know something that I found regarding tableviews. I have UITableView whose items are being generated dynamically, means rows. Now whenever I scroll UITableView to end and stretch the scroll up and release it (u know iPhone style), my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` gets called. I noticed this because I had my NSLog there. Does this happen normally?

Actually, thing is I am also lazy loading image for UIImageView in each row inside tis method, so I think because of this my lazy loader is also getting called and I don't want this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a normal behaviour. The method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is getting called for the new rows which are now visible. This makes the whole table more responsive, because it does not have to render all the rows at same time.

Comment: Hi thanks. And do i have to let my lazy image loader which is being loaded from webservice also happen. I mean whenever i scroll table like that, it calls.

Comment: Yes, you could call your image lazy loader always when the cellForRowAtIndexPath is getting called. That should increase the performance..